# what does this line of regular expression mean in python? : (r'^(?:.{4}\-){3}.{4}$')

Tags: python-3.x

RegEx:

```
(r'^(?:.{4}\-){3}.{4}$')
```

I want help in understanding this line of Regular Expression bit by bit:

```
import re

is_grouping = re.compile(r'^(?:.{4}\-){3}.{4}$').match
is_consecutive = re.compile(r'(.)\1{3}').search
is_valid = re.compile(r'^[456]\d{15}$').match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the details here: https://regex101.com/r/H61azp/1

```
" ^(?:.{4}\-){3}.{4}$ "

^ asserts position at start of a line
```

- Non-capturing group (?:.{4}-){3}

  1. {3} Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
  2. .{4} matches any character (except for line terminators)
  3. {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
- - matches the character - literally (case sensitive)

  1. .{4} matches any character (except for line terminators)
- {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
- $ asserts position at the end of a line